# Flutter image_picker pickImage camera buttons

Tags: flutter, android-camera

In my app, I use *carImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)* to take a picture.  This works fine. After taking the picture, two buttons are displayed, Save and Cancel (or something like that, the labels are in Swedish.) After pressing Save, I am returned to my app code.

I would prefer not to have these buttons. I want to return to my code immediately after taking the picture, without having to press a button.

Is this possible? How?

(I cannot use the camera plugin due to its strange behaviour om Samsung Galaxy, a known problem.)